# How to reference the primary key at the derived part of the same table?

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, rdbms, object-oriented-database

Let's consider the following two, simplified tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE payments
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    method int,
    method_name name,
    total numeric,
    payment_date timestamp without time zone,
    is_seccessful boolean,
    data jsonb
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE subscription_payments
(
    subscription_id int,
    parent_id bigint,

   CONSTRAINT pk_subscription_id FOREIGN KEY (subscription_id)
       REFERENCES subscriptions (id)
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
INHERITS (payments);
```

Now, how can I create a foreign key reference of `subscription_payments.parent_id` to `payments.id` in which it wouldn't reference other inheriting tables?

In other words, how can I reference `subscription_payments.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a bridge you can simply reference payments, this would then guarantee that a payment was made.

```sql
CREATE TABLE subscription_payments
(
    subscription_id int,
    parent_id bigint,

    primary key (subscription_id, parent_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_subscription_id FOREIGN KEY (subscription_id)
        REFERENCES subscriptions (id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_parent_id  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id )
        REFERENCES payments(id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. One more thing though, wouldn't directly referencing `payments` mean referencing all other inhering tables?

Comment: if you have more tables you can add them as reference as long they have one or the other column in common. That means if there is a table that has the payment Id in his repertoire, you can add it, even it has nothing to do with subscrition. But be aware that you don't build ring references